# What is the main problem in the YAML file?

Tags: kubernetes

When I want to run the following YAML file, I get the following error:

error: error parsing pod2.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
name: wp
    image: wordpress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix indentation and also `containers` is a list:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: wp
    image: wordpress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Comment: How can I get the consumed resources of a pod?

Comment: kubectl top pod